# Can't import OpenCV in python3.4.3

Tags: linux, opencv

I searched how to predict my own digit image using **Google TensorFlow**.

I used 64bit Red Hat Linux.

I installed Python3.4.3, other related development environments and TensorFlow version 0.6.0.

Then, I tried to write code for digit prediction.
Firstly, I need to read images in my python program.
So, I searched how to read images in python then I found **OpenCV** (http://opencv.org/)

I installed OpenCV(version:3.1.0) using **cmake**.
After installing OpenCV, I tried to import **cv2**(OpenCV function) in order to read image.
But I cannot import cv2 and ImportError occured as the following.

```
ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I tried to solve this problem by changing **default PYTHONPATH**.

For example:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

I tried to add some code in my python program.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/python/lib/python3.4')
```

But the above two steps cannot solve the problem **ImportError: No module named 'cv2'**.
So, I search how to solve this problem and I tried to solve with many other ways. But no success.

How can I import cv2 in my python program?

OpenCV Installation steps are as follow:

```
>>> yum install cmake
** Download OpenCV latest version from it's official site **
>>> cd /directory of OpenCV/
>>> mkdir release
>>> cd release
>>> cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE   -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON ..
>>> make && make install
>>> echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf
>>> ldconfig  
>>> echo "PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
>>> echo "export PKG_CONFIG_PATH" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't directly answer your question—perhaps an OpenCV expert can help with that—but TensorFlow includes [reasonably comprehensive support](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/image.html) for manipulating images. If your images are in JPEG format you can use [`tf.image.decode_jpeg()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/image.html#decode_jpeg) to convert them to tensors; likewise [`tf.image.decode_png()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/image.html#decode_png) supports PNG images.